# How to remove CRLF and a new line from text file using batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, newline

Goal is to do the following using batch script:

1. Extract hostname from windows machine.
2. apply sha256 hash on hostname value (obtained from step1).

My system's hostname is: **W0000000000ZQ**

My batch script looks like this:

```
@echo off
hostname>hostname.txt
CertUtil -hashfile hostname.txt SHA256 //<- this is generating wrong sha256 string because
                                       //   the above generated file contains CRLF and a new line
                                       //   screenshot of this file provided below.
CertUtil -hashfile hostname-manual.txt SHA256 //<- this is generating correct sha256 string because
                                              //   i manually created this file and pasted hostname
                                              //   only (W0000000000ZQ) without CRLF and new line.
                                              //   screenshot of this file provided below.
```

**hostname.txt:**

[image]

**hostname-manual.txt**

[image]

**Output from the script:**

[image]

Can you please suggest how to remove CRLF and a newline from "hostname.txt" so that Certutil will pick correct string to generate sha256 value.

Comment: A slight nitpick: you're not getting a CRLF _and_ a newline; you're just getting a CRLF, which _is_ the newline.

Comment: Try `< nul > "hostname.txt" set /P ="%ComputerName%"`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following saves the hostname to a file without the trailing CRLF.

```
for /f %%h in ('hostname') do (>hostname.txt <nul set /p unused=%%h)
```